# Rails External Api Call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest-client

How to call an external api using rest-client gem with api token?

I am doing something like this

```
RestClient.get('api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797', headers={appid: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})
```

But this gives me an unauthorized response. What is the proper name for token header?
[Open weather api](https://openweathermap.org/appid)

I can't figure this out.

Comment: it looks like you can append it to the URI if you're in a pinch. `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&appid=xxxxxxxxx`

Answer (score 2):

Try using string interpolation to put the `API_TOKEN` into the `url`so it looks like this.

> http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901&APPID=1111111111

So:

```
RestClient.get("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=2172797&APPID=#{API_TOKEN}")
```

Answer (score -1):

I should put APPID in params hash.
So the best solution I found was create ENV variable and use it in my file.  Then I can just call.

```
RestClient.get 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London', {params: {APPID: API_KEY}}
```